# C++ jsoncpp: Segfault while reading json file in a loop

Tags: c++, json, segmentation-fault, jsoncpp

Json file:

```
[
    {"A":"sample1","B":"sample2","C":"sample3,"D":"sample4"},       
    {"A":"sample5","B":"sample6","C":"sample7,"D":"sample8"}, 
    {"A":"samplea","B":"sampleb","C":"sampleb,"D":"sampleb"},
    .
    .
    .
    }
]
```

I have 2075980 such entries in  my input file

```
struct entry_t 
{
    U64 param;
}
entry_t entry; 
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
ifstream test("json_file", ifstream::binary);    
if(!reader.parse(test, root, false))
{
    cout << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages() << endl;}
else
{ 
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < root.size(); i++)
    {  
        entry.param   = root[i].get("A", "null").asInt();
    }
}
```

above code works fine until 472783th loop. in the following loop,  getting a seg fault while trying to access "entry.param"

I am new to C++ and jsoncpp and not able to figure out the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: How many items do you have in your json file?

Comment: @ArashMohammadi _"I have 2075980 such entries in my input file "_

Comment: why do you read the file as a binary?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in a Windows OS, JsonCPP allocates **2.5 GB** to store your file in memory...

You must switch to 64bit or use another native lib with a smaller memory footprint ([see here](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark))

[image: memory usage]

Comment: Or use a better way of loading the file, that doesn't need to have the whole thing in memory at once.